# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When i'm try to run my command i'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')` error. I'm on discord.js 13, and here is my code

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const translate = require('@iamtraction/google-translate');
module.exports = {
  name: 'fact',
  description: 'Випадковий факт',
  category: 'Fun',
  async run({ interaction, bot }) {
    const response = await fetch('https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en');
    await response.json().then(res => {
    const translated = translate(res, { to: 'uk' });
      interaction.reply({
        embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Факт').setDescription(translated.text.join("\n")).setColor('RANDOM')]
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`translate` function returns a `Promise` object, so you have to put await keyword infront of `translate` function as below.

```
await response.json().then(async res => {
const translated = await translate(res, { to: 'uk' });
```

Comment: Now i'm getting this error `syntaxerror: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: put async keyword before res and after then